# No little images for TIP, NOTE nor IMPORTANT

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-epub3

I use https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-epub3 to export to kf8 for Kindle. The result looks beautiful but is misses the little images next to TIP, NOTE and IMPORTANT. I guess the files are missing or there is an error in the CSS. How can I fix it?

I use this command to render the kf8 version:

```
asciidoctor-epub3 -D output -a ebook-format=kf8 book.adoc
```

Comment: Which version of the epub backend are you using?

Comment: asciidoctor-epub3-1.5.0.dev.gem which I build from the Github repository last week.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, please create an issue

Comment: Done. https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-epub3/issues/50

Comment: Thanks for the bug report!